# Calculator for options in Tkinter - no output and no error

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a calculator using Tkinter for options. The idea is that when you write "European Call", "American Put"... it computes the price.

I am trying with if statements but it does not work and no error appears. I tried to do it for only 1 type and it works but adding the if elif seems to have broken it. Could you please help me?.

```
    import tkinter as tk
    import numpy as np

    root= tk.Tk()
    root.wm_title('Stonks')


    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 470, height = 480)
    canvas1.pack()

    label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Calculate Option Price')
    label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
    canvas1.create_window(235, 40, window=label1)

    entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
    canvas1.create_window(330, 100, window=entry1)

    entry2 = tk.Entry (root) 
    canvas1.create_window(330, 140, window=entry2)

    entry3 = tk.Entry (root) 
    canvas1.create_window(330, 180, window=entry3)

    entry4 = tk.Entry (root) 
    canvas1.create_window(330, 220, window=entry4)

    entry5 = tk.Entry (root) 
    canvas1.create_window(330, 260, window=entry5)

    entry6 = tk.Entry (root) 
    canvas1.create_window(330, 300, window=entry6)

    entry7 = tk.Entry (root) 
    canvas1.create_window(330, 330, window=entry7)

    entry8 = tk.Entry (root) 
    canvas1.create_window(240, 460, window=entry8)

    label1 = tk.Label(root, text='     Spot Value (S):')
    label1.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
    canvas1.create_window(160, 100, window=label1)

    label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Strike (K):')
    label2.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
    canvas1.create_window(160, 140, window=label2)

    label3 = tk.Label(root, text='         Interest Rate (r):')
    label3.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
    canvas1.create_window(160, 180, window=label3)

    label4 = tk.Label(root, text='         Volatility (sigma):')
    label4.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
    canvas1.create_window(160, 220, window=label4)

    label5 = tk.Label(root, text='        Time to maturity (T) :')
    label5.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
    canvas1.create_window(160, 260, window=label5)

    label6 = tk.Label(root, text='        Number of Steps (n):')
    label6.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
    canvas1.create_window(160, 300, window=label6)

    label7 = tk.Label(root, text='        type:')
    label7.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
    canvas1.create_window(160, 330, window=label7)`

    def BinomialModel():
        S= float(entry1.get())
        K = float(entry2.get())
        r = float(entry3.get())
        sigma= float(entry4.get())
        T = float(entry5.get())
        n = int(entry6.get())
        answer=str(entry7.get())
        dt=T/n
        u=np.exp(sigma*np.sqrt(dt))
        v=1/u
        p=(np.exp(r*dt) -v)/(u-v)
        Stree=np.zeros((n+1,n+1))
        V=np.zeros((n+1,n+1))
        U=np.zeros((n+1,n+1))

    def on_button(event=None): 

    answer = entry7.get().strip().lower()

      if answer in ("European Call"):
         for i in range(0,n+1):
              for j in range(0,i+1):
                Stree[j][i]=S*(u**(i-j))*(v**(j))
                V[j][i]=np.maximum(Stree[j][i]-K,0)  
             
         for i in range(n,-1,-1):
            for j in range(0,i+1):
                if i==n:  
                    U[j][i]=V[j][i]
                else:
                    U[j][i]=np.exp(-r*dt)*((U[j][i+1]*p + U[j+1][i+1]*(1-p)))    
                    OptionPrice1=U[0][0]
                    
        label8 = tk.Label(root, text= OptionPrice1,font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'),bg='white')
        canvas1.create_window(240, 440, window=label8)
    
    elif answer in ("European Put"):
        for i in range(0,n+1):
            for j in range(0,i+1):
                Stree[j][i]=S*(u**(i-j))*(v**(j))
                V[j][i]=np.maximum(K-Stree[j][i],0)  
            
        for i in range(n,-1,-1):
            for j in range(0,i+1):
                if i==n:  
                    U[j][i]=V[j][i]
                else:
                    U[j][i]=np.exp(-r*dt)*((U[j][i+1]*p + U[j+1][i+1]*(1-p)))    
                    OptionPrice2=U[0][0]
                        
        label8 = tk.Label(root, text= OptionPrice2,font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'),bg='white')
        canvas1.create_window(240, 440, window=label8)
    
    elif answer in ("American Call"):
        for i in range(0,n+1):
            for j in range(0,i+1):
                Stree[j][i]=S*(u**(i-j))*(v**(j))
                V[j][i]=np.maximum(Stree[j][i]-K,0)    

        for i in range(n,-1,-1):
            for j in range(0,i+1):
                if i==n: 
                    U[j][i]=V[j][i]
                else:
                    U[j][i]=np.maximum(V[i][j],np.exp(-r*dt)*((U[j][i+1]*p + U[j+1][i+1]*(1-p))))
                    OptionPrice3=U[0][0]
                        
        label8 = tk.Label(root, text= OptionPrice3,font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'),bg='white')
        canvas1.create_window(240, 440, window=label8)

    elif answer in ("American Put"):

        for i in range(0,n+1):
            for j in range(0,i+1):
                Stree[j][i]=S*(u**(i-j))*(v**(j))
                V[j][i]=np.maximum(K-Stree[j][i],0)

        for i in range(n,-1,-1):
            for j in range(0,i+1):
                if i==n:  #that is the end of the matrix, final value=intrinsic value
                    U[j][i]=V[j][i]
                else:
                    U[j][i]=np.maximum(V[i][j],np.exp(-r*dt)*((U[j][i+1]*p + U[j+1][i+1]*(1-p))))
                    OptionPrice4=U[0][0]

        label8 = tk.Label(root, text= OptionPrice4,font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'),bg='white')
        canvas1.create_window(240, 440, window=label8)

    button1 = tk.Button(text='Calculate Option Price', command=BinomialModel, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(240, 420, window=button1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Sorry for copying the whole code but I don't really know where the problem is.

Comment: You called `lower()`, so how do you expect `answer in ("European Call")` to be True?  Also you should use `==` instead of `in`.

Comment: You should probably have objects for `EuropeanCall`, `AmericanCall`, `EuropeanPut`, `AmericanPut`, and call the pricing on them.